# Elegoo Mars 2 is printing randomly in the wrong places

Tags: resin, quality

After damaging my LCD plate while removing hardened resin (after my FEP failed and resin hardened onto the LCD) my printer started to harden resin in areas around the printed part. It started out being a bit of resin partially hardened to the FEP. I then replaced the damaged LCD with a new one, but the problem is getting worse. It now builds whole areas that are not part of the print. It seems like the LCD is creating these printed areas.

Is there a solution to this? I can't find anybody else having this problem.

Correction, Elegoo has a firmware update which is to correct a problem where resin is hardened all over the plate. This update seems to have failed to completely correct my problems.

First image is before update, second and third images are after the update.

[image: Before firmware update]

[image: After firmware update]

[image: Strange printing flaws, post firmware update]

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue?

Comment: Yes, I resolved it, with a suggestion from Elegoo. The problem was with a faulty LCD panel. When I started a test of the new panel, without a tray of resin, the panel was obviously flickering badly. Replacing the panel with a new one solved it.

Comment: It is great that you found a solution, however... Please post your solution as an answer and **not** as a comment. Then please mark it as the accepted answer... Otherwise the whole Q&A mechanism of the site tends to fall apart. Thank you.